# Метод, который считает среднее

Tags: java

Всем привет.
Есть класс `Wagon` и класс `Train`, которые находятся в отношениях "has a". В классе `Train` необходимо реализовать методы:

1) нахождения сколько всего поезд может перевезти в тоннах
2) среднее на вагон.

```
public class Wagon {
    int m;

    public Wagon (int m) {
        this.m = m;
    }
}
```

```
public class Train {
    int count = 0;
    Wagon wag;

    public Train(Wagon wag) {
        this.wag = wag;
        count++;
    }

    public findCargo() {//общий вес




    }
    public findAverage() //средний на вагон.

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так и как создать такой метод?

Comment: У вас связь один вагон к одному поезду. Сделайте поле вагон в классе поезда массивом(статическим или динамическим из коллекций), дальше до решения будет не трудно дойти

Comment: я проходил только массивы, как его можно создать и использовать здесь если мы не знаем его размер и сколько объектов будет создано?

Comment: Варианта два:
1) Создать самому динамический массив, это когда количество элементов доходит до того количества которое вы указывали при создании массива, и в этот момент создается массив в два раза больше и туда копируются элементы
2) Или использовать готовое решение [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде:

```
public Train(Wagon wag) {
    this.wag = wag;
    count++;
```

Конструктор делает ссылку на саму же себя и за чего остается со значением `null`.

Вариант ниже подойдет если количество вагонов будете указывать вы и именно со статичным массивом необходимо работать по заданию.

```
public class Train {

  Wagon[] wag;

  public Train(int num) {
    this.wag = new Wagon[num];
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Train train = new Train(3);
  train.wag[0] = new Wagon(4);
  train.wag[1] = new Wagon(2);
  train.wag[2] = new Wagon(6);

  System.out.println(train.findCargo());

  System.out.println(train.findAverage());


  }

  public int findCargo() {

    int x = 0;

    for (Wagon w : wag) {

      x+=w.m;
    }

    return x;

  } 

  public int findAverage() {

    return this.findCargo()/wag.length;
  }
}
```

Comment: Этот момент не очень понятен. Не могли бы пояснить? Спасибо заранее public class Train {

  Wagon[] wag;

  public Train(int num) {
    this.wag = new Wagon[num];

Comment: Ага, теперь верно. Но это все равно не решает проблемы которую указал Алексей выше. Если вы сейчас работаете со статичными массивами и число и вес вагонов можете заранее указать в коде то используйте мой вариант. Если же это будут неизвестные то или придется код усложнять или все же присмотритесь к коллекциям.

Comment: В этом варианте конструктора при создании объекта Train в виде аргумента передается число значение которого будет означать размер массива wag в этом объекте. Т.е. количество вагонов которые можно будет поместить в этот поезд.

Comment: спасибо, но все равно не понятна строчка this.wag = new Wagon[num]; что мы ей передаем?

Comment: и не очень понимаю как здесь работает агрегация? Кто может подсказать?

Comment: this.wag - это значит что мы обращаемся к перменной экземпляра класса Train который создается этим конструктором. Следовательно то что мы присвоим этой переменной будет хранится именно в объекте который сейчас создаём.    new Wagon[num] - значит что мы к нашей ссылочной переменной wag создаваемого объекта Train создаем объект массива с размером = num

Comment: А агрегация здесь при том что объекты Wagon хранящиеся в массиве являются частями объекта Train.

Comment: спасибо! Буду дальше разбираться, прояснение появились